# How to add a sorting Image to a GridView Header while working with ObjectDataSource or EntityDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, objectdatasource

I want to know how can we use sorting image inside `GridView` header while we use `ObjectDataSource` or Entity Framework. Because that has direct calling feature and also having sorting expression.

So, how can i use `GridView.RowCreated` event and get the sort expression to bind the sorting image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was for older ASP.NET 2.0 days. ASP.NET 4.0 allows us to specify it as a `asp:GridView` property

> MSDN Links
>
> 1. [SortedAscendingHeaderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sortedascendingheaderstyle.aspx)
> 2. [SortedDescendingHeaderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorteddescendingheaderstyle.aspx)

GridView Markup

```
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc" />
```

css

```
.datatable th
{
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:2px 4px;
    color:#333333;
    border-bottom:solid 2px #bbd9ee;
}
.datatable th a
{ 
    text-decoration:underline;
    padding-right:18px; 
    color:#000;
}
.datatable th.sortasc a { background:url(../Images/asc.gif) right center no-repeat; }
.datatable th.sortdesc a { background:url(../Images/desc.gif) right center no-repeat; }
```

Please note that the `asp:GridView` has been assigned `CssClass="datatable"`.

You might also want to check out [SortedAscendingCellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sortedascendingcellstyle.aspx) and [SortedDescendingCellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorteddescendingcellstyle.aspx)

For old fashioned way, try this. http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/10/a_yui_datatable_styled_gridvie.html

Comment: Adding the two classes and tag inside the `GridView` didn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: can you addit as another question. will take a look at it

Comment: I went with RowCreated method and I have it working. Thank you